# How do I activate red underline of C++ on VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, settings

I have unintentionally deactivated the red underlining on VS Code while writing c++.
How can I enable it back?

I already have the c/c++ microsoft extension installed.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your `c_cpp_properties.json` file?

Comment: If that doesn't work, the settings.json might have something. It shouldn't be that hard to trace down.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I had the same problem and I found it.

Simply, from /{YOUR_PROJECT}/.vscode/settings.json, delete this line.

```json
{
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled" // delete this line
}
```